# Excel 2010 - How to "merge" tables without repetition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say I have a list of the same people in two tables. Table A lists the shirts a user has and Table B lists the pants. A user can have multiple shirts and pants. Example:

Table A:

USER    SHIRTS

1______red

1______blue

2______green

3______red

3______black

3______white

Table B

USER    PANTS

1______blue

1______red

1______green

2______black

2______blue

3______white

I need to somehow merge them so that it doesn't show repeats. My current merging strategy using VLOOKUP results in all possible combinations that a user may have, so for example since user 1 has two shirts and three pants, the merge results in 6 rows for user 1 (2 shirts x 3 pants = 6 combinations).

What I want is a merge that looks like this:

USER    SHIRTS  PANTS

1______red_____blue

1______blue____red

1_____________green

2______green___black

2______________blue

3______red_____white

3______black

3______white

I want it to simply list it in total with the number of rows being determined by whichever column requires the most. For example, user 3 has 3 shirts and 1 pant, so it has 3 rows due to the shirts but only one entry in the pants column. If a user has 100 shirts but only 2 pants, then they will have 100 rows in the column and only 2 rows of the pants column will be filled, the rest being empty.

Comment: Scripting solutions are welcome :)

Comment: You say you have a current "Strategy", what is it?

Comment: Current strategy involves copying the table headers into one sheet and then using VLOOKUP based on the USERID to populate the columns, e.g. VLOOKUP([@USER_ID],ShirtsTable, 2, 0). Note that I have to convert the sheet into tables for this to work (with CTRL+T)

Comment: So you want to combine shirts and pants on the same record strictly by sequence in the history?  Are the users in consecutive or random order or can you sort them (are all records for a given user contiguous within each list, and in the same sequence between lists?)

Comment: Users can be sorted, and they are contiguous so User 1 on  a table will only be in one location on the list with all of its corresponding data (whether shirts or pants). Essentially I want something like User 1 --- List of all their shirts --- List of all their pants - as my headers, but it gets tricky because of the row counts and repetition issue.